# Jenkins Deployment - Powershell SCP Script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, scp

Good evening,

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that will connect to a remote server via SCP and upload or download files/folders. Ultimately this is the script that I would like Jenkins to run.

So far I'm using Posh-SSH and having good success. The only issue is, no matter what I have tried so far, it will always prompt me for my credentials. This, obviously, makes it not entirely automatic.

I have attached a few things I've tried. Hopefully someone can help me out with this!

The basic command I'm testing with:

```
get-scpfolder -computername '111.111.111.111' -credential $credential 
-remotefile "/var/myFolder" -localfile 'C:\Users\Me\destFolder'
```

Again, this works, but it requires me to enter my credentials.

I saw this command online:

```
$Password = "pass"
$User = "admin"
$ComputerName = "111.111.111.111"
$Command = "get-scpfolder -computername $ComputerName -credential $Credentials -localfolder 'C:\Users\Me' -remotefolder '/var/destFolder"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credentials #Connect Over SSH

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command # Invoke Command Over SSH
```

However this returns ExitStatus 1 and nothing happens. I have tried a few variations of the $Command including the credentials or not, for example, and I can't get any of it to work.